# How to print the .html file name on the top of the file using PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell

I have to concatenate many .html files in only one, this part i made it with the next command lines:

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
Get-Content *.html | Set-Content output.htm
```

And it ended like this:

> Operações  Base Legal da Isenção
> Internas e Interestaduais   Item 130 da Parte 1 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG
> Observações
> Produto constante do item 68 da Parte 15 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG.
> A isenção fica condicionada a que:
> a) o produto esteja beneficiado com isenção ou alíquota zero do II e o do IPI;
> b) a parcela relativa à receita bruta decorrente das operações previstas neste item esteja desonerada das contribuições para os PIS/PASEP e COFINS.
> Fica dispensado o estorno do crédito na saída de mercadoria beneficiada, na hipótese de saída realizada por estabelecimento industrial ou importador.
> O benefício não se aplica nas operações internas destinadas a órgãos da Administração Pública Estadual Direta, suas fundações e autarquias, hipótese em que será aplicada a isenção prevista no item 136 da Parte 1 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG.
>
> Operações  Base Legal da Isenção
> Internas e Interestaduais   Item 130 da Parte 1 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG
> Observações
> Em relação a esta mercadoria, a legislação estadual faz referência ao código 2937.39.11. Todavia, o referido código foi alterado para 2922.50.31, desde 2012.
> Produto constante do item 63 da Parte 15 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG.
> A isenção fica condicionada a que:
> a) o produto esteja beneficiado com isenção ou alíquota zero do II e o do IPI;
> b) a parcela relativa à receita bruta decorrente das operações previstas neste item esteja desonerada das contribuições para os PIS/PASEP e COFINS.
> Fica dispensado o estorno do crédito na saída de mercadoria beneficiada, na hipótese de saída realizada por estabelecimento industrial ou importador.
> O benefício não se aplica nas operações internas destinadas a órgãos da Administração Pública Estadual Direta, suas fundações e autarquias, hipótese em que será aplicada a isenção prevista no item 136 da Parte 1 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG.

This is two files in one. What I need is to make the files name be printed on the top of each text begin.

I have one .batch file what does it (but is so much slow to process), with the following command lines:

```
#type *.html > output.htm

@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.html) do (
    if not %%~nxi == output.htm (
        echo %%~nxi >> output.htm
        type "%%i" >> output.htm
        echo. >> output.htm
    )
)
```

Exemple of how have to be:

> index_103d62b6.php.html
>
> Operações  Base Legal da Isenção
> Internas e Interestaduais   Item 130 da Parte 1 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG
> Observações
> Produto constante do item 68 da Parte 15 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG.
> A isenção fica condicionada a que:
> a) o produto esteja beneficiado com isenção ou alíquota zero do II e o do IPI;
> b) a parcela relativa à receita bruta decorrente das operações previstas neste item esteja desonerada das contribuições para os PIS/PASEP e COFINS.
> Fica dispensado o estorno do crédito na saída de mercadoria beneficiada, na hipótese de saída realizada por estabelecimento industrial ou importador.
> O benefício não se aplica nas operações internas destinadas a órgãos da Administração Pública Estadual Direta, suas fundações e autarquias, hipótese em que será aplicada a isenção prevista no item 136 da Parte 1 do Anexo I do RICMS/MG.

Where "index_103d62b6.php.html" is the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are currently in the folder with all the HTML files,try this:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$_.Name | Add-Content output.html; Get-Content $_ | Add-Content output.html }
```

Answer (score 0):

For all files **html**, may you need some like:

---

```powershell
Get-ChildItem *.html -exclude output.html | Foreach-Object { $_.Name; Get-Content -Raw $_ } | Set-Content output.html -Encoding String
# or #
ls *.html -e output.html | % { $_.Name; gc -Raw $_ } | sc output.html -Encoding String
```

---

For all files **html**, and output in **htm** may you need some like:

---

```powershell
Get-ChildItem *.html | Foreach-Object { $_.Name; Get-Content -Raw $_ } | Set-Content output.htm -Encoding String
# or #
ls *.html | % { $_.Name; gc -Raw $_ } | sc output.htm -Encoding String
```

---

For all files **htm**, and output in **htm** may you need some like:

---

```powershell
Get-ChildItem *.htm -exclude output.htm | Foreach-Object { $_.Name; Get-Content -Raw $_ } | Set-Content output.htm -Encoding String
# or #
ls *.html -e output.htm | % { $_.Name; gc -Raw $_ } | sc output.htm -Encoding String
```

---

So sorry about my limited **English!**

---